# Printing a Dialogbox in Java

Tags: java, printing

I need to print a dialog box with some components, onto a printer and yes defiantly on a paper. The app on which i am working is java desktop app made using swings. I am using Netbeans 7.2 for that. How can I achieve this task? Do I need to import any external libraries or can this be done using the in-built Java libraries.

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you're trying to do, and what you've tried / what problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the in-built java libraries... from "javax.swing"

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Message Content");
```

Comment: I am trying to implement the Printerjob class but all is in vain.

Comment: Raj it has to be printed on paper, not on a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.jOptionPane;

class DialogBox {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Your name ");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " your name /n another name ");
  }
}
```

I Hope this helped